# How could i set these buttons at the bottom of my div

Tags: html, css

[image: buttons]

I'm trying to put those two buttons at the bottom but the vertical-align:bottom don't seem to have any effects.

Both blocks are in a class "login-card" and the blue stuff are buttons/submit inside this class.

Here is my css :

```
.login-card {
  padding: 40px;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.login-card input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email], inputs {
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  padding: 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.login-card input[type=submit], input[type=button] {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Am i missing something obvious ?

EDIT, added Html :

```
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="login-card" id="firstCard">
      <h1>Fill the Wheel</h1>

        <form action="javascript:void(0);" name="members" onsubmit="rollIt()">
            <div id="dynamicInput">
               <input class="inputs" type="text" name="input1" placeholder='Type name' required>
               <input class="inputs" type="text" name="input2" placeholder='Type name' required>
               <input class="inputs" type="text" name="input3" placeholder='Type name' required>
           </div>
           <input type="button" id="addInput" class="login login-submit" value="Add a member">
           <input type="submit" id="rollWheel" name="login" class="login login-submit" value="Roll the wheel!">
       </form>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The vertical-align property will only work with table cells. Do you have any html you can share with us?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i edited the post to include the html part

Comment: Which buttons are you talking about ? The stop/mail the wheel or the two others ?

Comment: I'd like both submit & button to always fit the bottom of the div class login card. So in the first block : add/roll at the bottom; in the second block : stop/mail at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are at the bottom of the form, their parent.  You need to take the padding-bottom off of login-card or something like that to give the buttons room to move down.

Also, here is an answer to your problem with the right box

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
</div>

.logincard:after {
   content: "";
   display: inline-block;
   height: 100%;
   vertical-align: bottom;
}
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: But the StopWheel/Mail are also in a div class="login-card" and are respectively input button/submit;
Yet they don't stick to the bottom (as seen in the right side of the screenshot)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to Stack, so I'm still trying to figure all the posting stuff out.